# Saving recorded video to phone gallary?

Tags: flutter

How do I save videos I have recorded inside the app with the `camera` package, and have access to the local File, to the phone gallery?

In the past, I used `gallary_saver` package which works well like this:

```
await GallerySaver.saveVideo(PATH_TO_FILE);
```

Now this package is not maintained anymore and I couldn't find a suitable package for replacement.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `permission_handler` package to request and check permissions, and then use the `path_provider` package to get the local file path, and finally, use platform-specific code to trigger the media scan for the saved file.

Here's a step-by-step guide:

1. Add Dependencies:
   Make sure you have the necessary dependencies in your `pubspec.yaml` file:

   dependencies:
   camera: ^0.10.0+2
   path_provider: ^2.0.14
   permission_handler: ^12.3.0
2. Request Permissions:
   Before saving the video to the gallery, make sure you have the necessary permissions. You can use the `permission_handler` package for this:

   import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

   ```
   Future<void> _requestPermission() async {
     await Permission.storage.request();
   }
   ```
3. Save Video and Trigger Media Scan:
   After recording a video, save it to a local file using the `path_provider` package. Once saved, use platform-specific code to trigger the media scan:

   import 'dart:io';

   ```
   import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
   import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

   Future<void> saveVideoToGallery(XFile videoFile) async {
     try {
       // Request storage permission
       await _requestPermission();

       // Get the app's documents directory
       final appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
       final appDocPath = appDocDir.path;

       // Generate a unique file name for the video
       final fileName = 'video_${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.mp4';

       // Move the video to the documents directory
       final newFilePath = '$appDocPath/$fileName';
       await File(videoFile.path).copy(newFilePath);

       // Trigger media scan
       if (Platform.isAndroid) {
         await _triggerMediaScan(newFilePath);
       }

       // On iOS, the media scan is automatic, so no need to trigger it

       print('Video saved to gallery: $newFilePath');
     } catch (e) {
       print('Error saving video: $e');
     }
   }

   Future<void> _triggerMediaScan(String path) async {
     // Trigger media scan using platform-specific code
     // For Android, you may need to use a platform channel to call the MediaScannerConnection
     // For simplicity, you can use a package like 'external_path' to trigger a scan
     // Example using the 'external_path' package:
     // await ExternalPath.triggerStorageScan(path);
   }
   ```

   Note: The `_triggerMediaScan` function uses a placeholder. You may need to use a platform channel for Android to call the `MediaScannerConnection` to trigger a media scan. Alternatively, you can explore other plugins or packages that provide this functionality.

Remember to handle platform-specific code for triggering a media scan on Android.

Please make sure to check the documentation and compatibility of the packages for the latest updates.